# How can I access the Layer Enum of an image datablock in Python?

Tags: python, compositing-nodes, image

In Blender 2.79 I'm trying to access the different layers which are present in my MultilayerEXR files using Python. Basically, in my Node Editor, I have an Image node which offers me the various layers which are present in the file:

[image: Example]

I can call the name of the layer just fine using `bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes.active.layer`, which will output 'Base' in this example.

Now, following other examples here on this site, usually I can get the possible Enum Items using `bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes.active.bl_rna.properties['layer'].enum_items`. While this **does** return an Enum to me, it is always the same one: It will be `<bpy_collection[1], EnumProperty.enum_items>` in all cases. Calling the following:

```
bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes.active.bl_rna.properties['layer'].enum_items[0]
```

will always return

```
<bpy_struct, EnumPropertyItem("PLACEHOLDER")>
```

How can I retrieve the list of layers which is stored in the image?

Comment: I'd imagine the placeholder is the internal item "dummy" for a dynamic enum, which is filled once an image is selected for the node, as the layer names are within the image data.  [Would need to get the layer names from the image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65236/openexr-making-sense-of-rgb-float-values)

Comment: @batFINGER Makes sense. I was hoping that even if it was a dynamic Enum, it would be exposed in Python already. It has to be around somewhere, as it's drawn in the UI. Will follow the OpenEXR header path for a start, thanks  :)